# Cleaning gap between two polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

I have two layers, parcel and polygon. When I create a new building alongside a parcel it produces a gap between the parcel and building along the side.

How can I clean this gap or how to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Integrate tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000) to clean this gap:

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
> boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
> specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
> tolerance are considered identical or coincident.